# Problem #23 pg-94, Stein and Shakarchi

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

As an application of the Fourier transform, show that
there does not exist a function $I\in L^1(R^d,m)$ such that
$f*I = f$ for all $f\in L^1(R^d,m)$.

Comment: Sara, I noticed with this, and your other two questions you had not provided attempts or any specification to where you are having difficulty.
In order for others to really help you and to show respect for their time they should be added to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ I \in L^1 $ then from uniform integrability given any $\epsilon >0 $ there is a $ \delta(\epsilon) > 0 $ such that you have $ \int_E |I(x)|dm <\epsilon $ for all measurable $E$ with $ m(E) < \delta(\epsilon) $. Now choose characteristic function $ f_\delta = \chi_{B(0,\delta)}\in L^1 $ and assume your statement is true for some $ I \in L^1 $. Then you have to have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f_\delta(x-y)I(y)dy = f_\delta (x) $$ Take $ x = 0 $ in the above and choose $ \delta$ such that $ m(B(0,\delta))= \delta(\epsilon)/2 $ you have the contracdiction
$$ 1 = f_\delta(0) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f_\delta(-y)I(y)dy = \int_{B(0,\delta)}I(y)dy <\epsilon $$

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton, I fully understood the core idea of your beautifully written proof. 
Thanks again for your time. 
:)

Comment: @SaraTancredi You're welcome :) Would you mind accepting it as an answer by clicking on the tick mark beside ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know Fourier transform, and in particular how it behave with respect to convolution product, the question is quite easy. Indeed, if $g$ and $h$ are integrable functions, then the relationship $\widehat{f*g}(x)=\widehat f(x)\widehat g(x)$, and the Fourier transform of an integrable function is continuous .

Otherwise, you can consider mollifiers, that is, non-negative smooth function with support contained in $B(0,n^{-1})$, of integral $1$. Take $(\phi_n)$ such a sequence, and show that $\phi_n*I\to I$ converge almost everywhere to $I$.

Comment: Hey Davide, Thank you so much for answering my problem. Davide, I don't know much about Fourier Transform and its behavior w.r.t convolution. Can you please tell me, how FT works with convolution. I mean their mutual behavior. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: @SaraTancredi I've added details.

Comment: thank you for your precious time. I understood your ideas after some Google browsing.
Thanks.